How to parallelize transformer model for machine translation on 8 GPUs?
I am attempting to perform machine translation using a transformer model in a manner almost identical to the original article. While the model works reasonably well, it requires greater computational resources. To address this, I ran the model on a computer with 8 GPU processors, but I lack experience in this area.
I tried to make the necessary adjustments for parallelization:
transformer = nn.DataParallel(transformer)
transformer = transformer.to(DEVICE)

However, due to my lack of experience, things are not working well. Specifically, I have been stuck for a long time on the following error message:
File "C:\Projects\MT005\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 5382,     
in multi_head_attention_forward raise RuntimeError(f"The shape of the 2D attn_mask is {attn_mask.shape}, but should be {correct_2d_size}.")   
RuntimeError: The shape of the 2D attn_mask is torch.Size([8, 64]), but should be (4, 4).  

Could someone help me solve this problem and get the model running on all 8 GPUs?

Can you provide a [mre]?

Add your own findings from isolating the root-cause of why [8,64] collided into [4,4] expectation ( what / where changed in code )

This question is similar to: Trying to Train Transformer Model for Machine Translation on Multi-GPU Setup. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Isn't this a case of a hacked ( be it human or machine-driven ) account? Asking the very same question within a week, after having been 13+ years a StackOverflow Community member? That sounds strange a human, (almost) a life-long member would do this, this very way, doesn't it?

It's not a hacked account; it's just me struggling with it for about a week, pulling my hair out in frustration from losing money and many hours wasted on AWS because of my lack of knowledge. I switched to Distributed Data Parallel now, hopefully it will work. I'm not very optimistic, though.
